# How to optimize performance of count query in symfony doctrine (mysql)?

Tags: mysql, symfony

I used to below query to count rows (~ 1M record and left join many table) :

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT u0_.id) AS sclr_0 
FROM user u0_ 
LEFT JOIN user_detail u1_ ON u0_.id = u1_.user_id 
LEFT JOIN recruitment_info r2_ ON u0_.id = r2_.user_id 
LEFT JOIN user u3_ ON u0_.master_account_id = u3_.id 
LEFT JOIN applicants_partners a4_ ON u0_.id = a4_.applicant_id 
LEFT JOIN partner p5_ ON a4_.partner_id = p5_.id 
WHERE u0_.type <> 'PARTNER' 
  AND u0_.is_delete = 0 
ORDER BY u0_.id DESC;
```

In my symfony, i got total :
 `$total = $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();`
It worked well but it took ~ 2.5s.

So, I would like to improve performance of it. I changed it into :

```
SELECT COUNT(u0_.id) AS sclr_0 
FROM user u0_ 
LEFT JOIN user_detail u1_ ON u0_.id = u1_.user_id 
LEFT JOIN recruitment_info r2_ ON u0_.id = r2_.user_id 
LEFT JOIN user u3_ ON u0_.master_account_id = u3_.id 
LEFT JOIN applicants_partners a4_ ON u0_.id = a4_.applicant_id 
LEFT JOIN partner p5_ ON a4_.partner_id = p5_.id 
WHERE u0_.type <> 'PARTNER' 
  AND u0_.is_delete = 0 
GROUP BY u0_.id 
ORDER BY u0_.id DESC;
```

The change here is remove `DISTINCT` and add `GROUP BY`.
Then I apply in symfony by count array result:

```
$result = $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
$total = count($result);
```

So the total is correct but this time, it took ~ 20s , OMG. When I tried run only raw query in Sequel Pro tool, it only took ~ 40ms. Maybe there is a problem in `getArrayResult()` ? . Please help me, thank you.

Comment: Simply remove all `LEFT JOIN`-ed tables from 1st query. PS. ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY issue possible. PPS. Aggregated values without the value which the data is aggregated by? how do you want to distinguish them?

Comment: Why are you joining to all of the other tables? It doesn't appear you are using them. Including the table definitions would be helpful too.

Answer (score 0):

As Akina mentions it in his comment, you can simplify this query by removing all the left join, the order by and even the distinct.

Your query will become something like this :

```
SELECT COUNT(u0_.id) AS sclr_0 
FROM user u0_ 
WHERE u0_.type <> 'PARTNER'
AND u0_.is_delete = 0;
```

And yes, you have to use getSingleScalarResult() on your Doctrine Query instance.